# Computing two dimensional arrays in memory

Tags: c++

First off, this is a homework problem that I'm not too sure of. Given the following:

```
const int TABLES = 10;
const int SEATS = 4;
Order diningRoom[TABLES][SEATS];
```

Assume array diningRoom starts at memory location 8000. How can the address of element `diningRoom[5][2]` be manually computed in terms of bytes?

```
A. 8000 + TABLES * 5 + 2
B. 8000 + sizeof(Order * TABLES * 2 + 5)
C. 8000 + sizeof(Order) * 5 * 2
D. 8000 + sizeof(Order) * (SEATS * 5 + 2)
```

I think the answer is D but I just wanted to ask SO before I submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**D is the right answer**

Arrays are laid out contiguously in memory so your array will actually look in memory as

```
Order diningRoom[10][4] == Order diningRoom[40]

0) Order | Order | Order | Order
1) Order | Order | Order | Order
2) Order | Order | Order | Order
3) Order | Order | Order | Order
4) Order | Order | Order | Order
5) Order | Order | Order | Order
6) Order | Order | Order | Order
7) Order | Order | Order | Order
8) Order | Order | Order | Order
9) Order | Order | Order | Order
```

since you're interested in `diningRoom[5][2]` you're actually asking for `diningRoom[SEATS*5 + 2]`

```
0) Order | Order | Order | Order
1) Order | Order | Order | Order
2) Order | Order | Order | Order
3) Order | Order | Order | Order
4) Order | Order | Order | Order
5) Order | Order |[Order]| Order
6) Order | Order | Order | Order
7) Order | Order | Order | Order
8) Order | Order | Order | Order
9) Order | Order | Order | Order
```

The answer which could have more resembled the right solution is C, but that is actually wrong since it doesn't keep into account [the array stride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array), i.e. `SEATS*sizeof(Order)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution A doesn't contain the size of a `Order` object anywhere.
=> Wrong.

`sizeof(Order * TABLES * 2 + 5)` in solution B makes no sense.
To start with, the class `Order` can't be multiplicated with integers...
=> Wrong.

If C would be correct, `diningRoom[1][2]` and `diningRoom[2][1]` are at the same memory location.
=> Wrong.

So, it's D.
If we imagine a `Order diningRoom[2][4];` as

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3]  
[1][0] [1][1] [1][2] [1][3]
```

the it's this in memory:

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3] [1][0] [1][1] [1][2] [1][3]
```

Now it should be easy to see why D is correct.
For element [x][y], x full "rows" have to be skipped,
and each row has 4 elements (in my example)